# DataTable TableTools initialisation

Tags: datatable, tabletools

With following imports, I have my datatable functioning:

```
<!-- DataTables CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="<c:url value="css/jquery.themeroller.css" />" />
<!-- TableTools CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="<c:url value="css/TableTools_JUI.css" />" />

<!-- jQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8"
    src="jQuery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>

<!-- DataTables -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8"
    src="jQuery/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<!-- TableTools -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8"
    src="jQuery/TableTools.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8"
    src="jQuery/ZeroClipboard.js"></script>
```

I am now trying to have tabletools options (print, save, copy, xls buttons) for my table.
I have inserted

```
oTable = $('#myTable').dataTable({
        "bJQueryUI" : true,
        "iDisplayLength" : 10,
        "sPaginationType" : "full_numbers",
        "aaSorting" : [ [ 7, "desc" ] ],
        "sDom": '<"H"lfr>t<"F"ip>' )}
```

but there is no change.

Do I have to change any of import queries or add css or something to get tabletools working?
I have tried "sDom":

```
"sDom": '<"H"lfr>t<"F"ip>'
"sDom": '<"H"lfrT>t<"F"ip>', 
"sDom": '<"H"lfr>t<"F"ip>T',
```

I had this for sSwfPath:

```
"C:/JAVA ENVIRONMENT/Workspace/Test/DisplayTable3/DataTables-1.9.4/extras/TableTools/media/swf/copy_cvs_xls_pdf.swf"
```

still nothing

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Change "C:/JAVA ENVIRONMENT/Workspace/Test/DisplayTable3/DataTables-1.9.4/extras/TableTools/media/swf/copy_cvs_xls_pdf.swf"
to a web path on your webserver. It's a common problem related to swf security. Found it on DataTables website. Also you can't redeclare sDom.

This is my working code with TableTools and ColVis:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#results').dataTable( {
        "sDom": 'T<"clear">Clfrtip',

        "oTableTools": {
            "sSwfPath": "http://192.168.78.7/cdtc/app/custom/libs/DataTables/extras/TableTools/media/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
```