# datatable tools copy, pdf. csv, excel export didnt work. only print is working

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

im using [datatables](http://datatables.net) for my front end requirements and it works good except im having an issue in exporting stuff e.g. copy, csv, excel and pdf, only print is working. Any ideas, clues, thoughts, help, suggestions, recommendation? I'm using version 1.10.6

I did link all the necessary libraries e.g. datatables js, css and datatables tools js. Below is my code for activating it on my script

```
$('#cigptable').DataTable( {
            "pagingType": "full_numbers",
            "dom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
            "tableTools": {
                "sSwfPath": "../../../plugins/datatables/extensions/TableTools/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
            },
            "oLanguage": {
            "oPaginate": {
              "sPrevious": '<i class="ion-ios-arrow-left"></i>',
              "sNext": '<i class="ion-ios-arrow-right"></i>'
            }
          }
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery dataTables - TableTools not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24837595/jquery-datatables-tabletools-not-working)

Comment: This question has answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24837595/1407478),  [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23222554/1407478), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25536782/1407478),  [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18513430/1407478), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29877651/1407478) and a lot more, also this is answered in comments dozen of times and is very well explained in the dataTables documentation and by examples.

Answer (score 0):

See [sSwfPath](http://datatables.net/extensions/tabletools/initialisation#sSwfPath) option documentation, below is an excerpt:

> `sSwfPath` Define the path of the SWF to be used by TableTools for copy to clipboard and saving a file locally operations. **If you are having problems with these operations, but not printing, this is very likely to be the issue.**

Most likely the problem is because of the incorrect path to the `copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf` file. Try to use [CDN](http://cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.4/) link instead:

```
//cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.4/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf
```

Quoting [Allan Jardine](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/26428/#Comment_26428), developer of DataTables:

> Also, it won't work from a local drive, unless you have a security exception set up for Flash. You can change the Global Security Settings here: http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html.

Comment: but it can print, i mean print is working yet the rest of the export buttons isnt working.

Comment: @CodeDemon, that's what the message says: *if all buttons, except printing, do not work, it's a problem with SWF file*.

Comment: @CodeDemon, the link is in the answer - `//cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.4/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf`